# (Bootstrap 4) Card borders rendered bad/different when used together with bg-color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

(Bootstrap 4.1.3)
I'm trying to customize a card. So first I put `border-danger`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card border-danger">
            <div class="card-header border-danger">
                Label
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                Text <br/>
                Text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I get the following:

[image: Border only]

So far so good.
Then I would try to change the background of the header using the same code but with:

```
...
<div class="card-header border-danger bg-white">
...
```

And so the border on the top side of the card degrades (it gets thinner):
[image]

Any combination of borders and bg-some_color on card, card-header, card-body, etc. causes such border problems (not only at the top, but also on the sides or bottom).

Could anyone solve this or give some hint how to avoid it?

Many thanks in advance!

--- Edit --------------------------------------------

I've made a new try with hello world template from bootstrap 4 website (cdn links to 4.0.0 not 4.1.3)
In FF Developer 64.0b2 (64-bit) it looks perfect.

In Crhome Version 70.0.3538.67 (Official Build) (64-bit) I get:
[image]

Then I pasted the code in codeply. In both FF and Chrome the results are ok. FF shows really 1 px thin borders, whereas Crhome displays thicker borders (but anyway uniform). Still on my local machine I get the problem ...

Comment: I couldn't replicate the issue, everything working fine for me. Probably there are some other CSS rules which are casing the issue.

Comment: Try styling the border by yourself: .card.border-danger {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

Comment: There are no other rules - just the standard bootstrap includes (bootstrap.min.css, jquery.slim.min.js, popper.min.js, bootstrap.min.js). I would style the border but not using px - it is not what BS4 uses.
And yes, I already played with px just to test it - it does not work any better. 
FYI I tested it Chrome 70.0.3538.67 (screenshots are from there). I'll try to simulate it in some *pen website and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is a browser/screen resolution problem only in Crhome Version 70.0.3538.67 (Official Build) (64-bit).

I have 2 different 4K/28" displays with 175% scaling set.
When I am in full-screen mode I get the error. When I resize the browser window I come to window sizes where it looks correct and others sizes where the error appears - it changes when one resizes the window.

There is no such issue on FF, Edge, and even on IE11.